# Dynamic Linq creation

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic

I am re-writing a query which is created in response to user's entry into text fields in order to offer some protection against SQL injection attack.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (FileNameID) FROM SurNames WHERE Surname IN
('Jones','Smith','Armitage') 
AND FileNameID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT (FileNameID) FROM FirstNames WHERE FirstName 
IN ('John','William') )
```

There can be up to 3 other tables involved in this process.
The parameter lists can be up to 50-100 entries so building a parameterized query is tedious and cumbersome.

I am trying to create a Linq query which should take care of the parameterization and offer the protection I need.

This gives me what I need

```
  var surnameValues = new[] { "Jones","Smith","Armitage" };
  var firstnameValues = new[] { "John","William" };

  var result = (from sn in db.Surnames
                from fn in db.FirstNames
                where surnameValues.Contains(sn.Surname) &&
                firstnameValues.Contains(fn.FirstName)
                select fn.FileNameID).Distinct().ToArray();
```

I now need a way to dynamically create this depending upon whether the user has selected/entered values in the surname or firstname text entry boxes?

Any pointers will be gratefully received

Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 1):

you could combine all the logic into the query;

```
var surnameValues = new[] { "Jones","Smith","Armitage" };
var firstnameValues = null;

// Set these two variables to handle null values and use an empty array instead
var surnameCheck= surnameValues ?? new string[0];
var firstnameCheck= firstnameValus ?? new string[0];

var result = (from sn in db.Surnames
            from fn in db.FirstNames
            where
            (!surnameCheck.Any() || surnameCheck.Contains(sn.Surname)) &&
            (!firstnameCheck.Any() || firstnameCheck.Contains(fn.FirstName))
            select fn.FileNameID).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Your query doesn't seem to have a join condition betwwen the Surnames table and the firstNames table?

You could dynamically build the query (as you appear to be doing I cross join I've used `SelectMany`)

```
var query=db.Surnames.SelectMany(sn=>db.FirstNames.Select (fn => new {fn=fn,sn=sn}));
if (surnameValues!=null && surnameValues.Any()) query=query.Where(x=>surnameValues.Contains(x.sn.Surname));
if (firstnameValues !=null && firstnameValues.Any()) query=query.Where(x=>firstnameValues.Contains(x.fn.FirstName));
var result=query.Select(x=>x.fn.FileNameID).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, that is very useful. I had partially gone down that route but was strugglng with as you pointed out some of the tables are not joined and where they are needed a full join which I couldnt find easily how to do in Linq. The main issue I had was with the declaration of the tables in case when there was no additional where clause added.  ie user only selects surname so no firstname modifier added to the where query.
Your example and use of the SelectMany was a real eye-opener - many thanks.

Comment: One thing that might help you is if you take a look at [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) it can give you the lambda syntax for your linq queries and will give you the same selectmany for the cross join. Can save a lot of time

Comment: I have looked briefly at LinqPad - do I need the paid version to really benfit?
 have hit another problem to do with Nulls if the Array hasnt been populated becasue the use didnt choose it !

    where (!surnameValues.Any() || surnameValues.Contains
          (sn.Surname)) &&
          (!firstnameValues.Any() || firstnameValues.Contains
          (fn.FirstName))

throws an exception - I have tried adding 
firstnameValues == null ||  in the where clause but it doesnt work ??

Comment: You don't need the paid version, but it does provide intellisense that helps with auto complete.  I've updated the answer so it handles null values for firstnameValues and surnameValues